# When will Ms CRM 5 be out

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2011

What can we expect from this new release?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blogs are reporting that it will be out in the second half of 2010

http://www.crmdynamics.net/2009/07/microsoft-dynamics-crm-5-0-due-out-second-half-of-2010/